How to get Images saved on a Python-Flask server to NextJs frontend via API
I have a NextJs frontend and a Python/Flask backend for the app I am building. I saved user details from the frontend to the backend database using this approach: User photo is uploaded to a folder on the flask server, then the photo filename alongside other details are saved to sqlite db using SQLAlchemy.
This works fine and the routes work well.
I created a route t get user details and it returns all the user info from the DB, including the photo name. I have an issue with knowing how to call up the photo in my frontend.
I tried:
using localhost:5000/uploads/photoname.jp, it gives 404.
Here is my Python code:
def GetOne(team_id):
    try:
        if Verify():
            result = Team.query.filter_by(team_id=team_id).first()
            if result:

                # photo_path = os.path.join('app', 'uploads', result.photo)
                photo_dir = 'app/uploads/'

                team_object = {
                        'team_id': result.team_id,
                        'first_name': result.first_name,
                        'last_name': result.last_name,
                        'sex': result.sex,
                        'email': result.email,
                        'position': result.position,
                        'location': result.location,
                        'photo': result.photo
                    }

                return jsonify({'success': True, 'message': team_object}), 200
            else:
                return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': 'Failed to Select Team'}), 500
        else:
            return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid or Expired Token Provided!'}), 403

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to Select Team Member', 'details': str(e)}), 500

Here is the NextJs code:
const ViewTeamMember = () => {
    const pathname = useParams()
    const team_id = pathname.user;
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [member, setMember] = useState([])
    const getTeamMember = () => {
        setLoading(true)
        HallieInterceptor.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/team/get-one/${team_id}`)
        .then(response => {
            setLoading(false)
            if(response.data.success){
                setMember(response.data.message)
            }
            else{
                alert(response.data.message)
            }
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getTeamMember()
    }, [])


    const handleDelete = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (confirm("Do you want to Delete this Record?")){
            const team_id = e.currentTarget.dataset.teamId;
            console.log(team_id)
            HallieInterceptor.delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/team/delete/${team_id}`)
            .then(response => {
                alert(response.data.message)
                getTeamMember()
            })
        }
        
    }
  return (

        <main className="flex-1 p-8">
          {/* Render main content here */}
          <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4 text-center py-2 border-b-2">Team Member</h2>
          <div>
            {
                 loading && (
                         <p className="py-4 text-center text-red-500 text-2xl font-semibold" colSpan={6}>
                             Loading ... Please Wait
                         </p>
                            )
            }
            {
                member && (
                    <div className="bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg overflow-hidden flex">
                    <div className="relative w-1/3 h-full">
                        {/* <Image
                        src={`http://localhost:5000/team_photos/${member.photo}`}
                        alt={`${member.first_name} ${member.last_name}`}
                        layout="fill"
                        objectFit="cover"
                        className="object-center"
                        /> */}
                        <img src={`http://localhost:5000/team_photos/${member.photo}`} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="p-6 w-2/3">
                        <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold text-gray-800 mb-2">
                        {member.first_name} {member.last_name}
                        </h2>
                        <p className="text-gray-600 mb-4">{member.position}</p>
                        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 mb-6">
                        <div>
                            <p className="text-gray-500 font-medium mb-1">Sex:</p>
                            <p className="text-gray-700">{member.sex}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p className="text-gray-500 font-medium mb-1">Email:</p>
                            <p className="text-gray-700">{member.email}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p className="text-gray-500 font-medium mb-1">Location:</p>
                            <p className="text-gray-700">{member.location}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p className="text-gray-500 font-medium mb-1">Created By:</p>
                            <p className="text-gray-700">{member.created_by}</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
                    
          </div>
        </main>

  )
}

export default ViewTeamMember

I knew that in ExpressJs, I can do so, but it doesn't seem to work in python.
How do I know where the image is located on the running server and be able to point to it?
I found out some suggestions that I should create an API endpoint to serve the image, but that will mean making tow API calls for the frontend, one to get the team member info and after than I will send back the photo name to the second endpoint to get the photo.
Is there a way to point to the location of the directory of the upload is and then append the image name to it in order to display it?
e.g <img src=http://localhost:5000/uploads/${user.photo_name}>
My frontend runs on localhost:3000 while backend is localhost:5000. Also on production, they will run on two separate servers and domains.
Please help, this is my first project using flask.
I am available for any clarifications.

I have been able to fix this issue after several hours.
For anyone having same issues, please note that you need to have your uploads folder inside a "static" folder at the root of your application.
Then add static_url_path='/static' to the instance of flasj:
app = Flask(name, static_url_path='/static')
Then at your frontend, use <img src=your-server-url/static/uploads/${photoname}>
